# "Publish immediately" with custom post status

Tags: post-status

I've registered a custom post status 'Editing'. Whenever a post is changed to use that status, the Publish time is set to the time the status was changed rather than 'Immediately'.

This is frustrating because my editors often don't notice this and publish posts 2 days in the past.

Here's the code:

```php
// Register Custom Post Status
function custom_post_status() {

    $args = array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Editing', 'Status General Name', 'futurism' ),
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Editing (%s)',  'Editing (%s)', 'futurism' ),
        'public'                    => false,
        'internal' => true,
        'private' => true,
        'protected' => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => true,
        );
    register_post_status( 'editing', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_status' );

// Add the option to the select menu in wp-admin because Wordpress doesn't do this for you
function append_post_status_list(){
    global $post;
    $complete = '';
    $label = '';
    if($post->post_status == 'editing'){
        $complete = ' selected=\"selected\"';
        $label = '<span id=\"post-status-display\"> Editing</span>';
    }
    echo '
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $("select#post_status").append("<option value=\"editing\" '.$complete.'>Editing</option>");
            $(".misc-pub-section label").append("'.$label.'");
        });
    </script>
    ';
}
add_action('admin_footer-post.php', 'append_post_status_list');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Few notes

- We can get the *"Publish immediately"* notice within the `post_submit_meta_box(()` when the `post_date_gmt` is equal to `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`.
- We can see [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/0358e2f4b8566b81c7779e9c88d42adc514ea04c/wp-includes/post.php#L3440-3453) within `wp_update_post()` and [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/0358e2f4b8566b81c7779e9c88d42adc514ea04c/wp-includes/post.php#L3011-3023) and [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/0358e2f4b8566b81c7779e9c88d42adc514ea04c/wp-includes/post.php#L3038-3054) within `wp_insert_post()`, how *draft-*, *pending-* or *auto-draft* posts are not date stamped.
- It looks like if we had a filter on the post status array [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/0358e2f4b8566b81c7779e9c88d42adc514ea04c/wp-includes/post.php#L3441) and [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/0358e2f4b8566b81c7779e9c88d42adc514ea04c/wp-includes/post.php#L3039) that we could easily fix this for the custom `editing` status. I also wonder if it would make sense to control this from the `register_post_status()` setup?
- It should be possible to modify the `post_date_gmt` within the `wp_insert_post_data` filter. Here we might try to get the previous post status from the `hidden_post_status` or `hidden_post_status` `$postarr` fields.
- The handy `transition_post_status` hook, fires before the post is updated but before the `wp_insert_post_data` filter. It will therefore not work to adjust the corresponding database value at this stage, because it will just be overriden shortly after.
- The `post_updated` hook fires after the post is updated. This hook provides an easy way to compare the post object *before* and *after* the update.

### Example

Here's one example how we can hook into `post_updated` to clear the `post_date_gmt` for the *post*, when the new status is *editing* and the previous is neither *publish* or *editing*:

```
add_action( 'post_updated', function( $post_ID, $post_after, $post_before ) use ( &$wpdb )
{
    if( 
           'editing' === $post_after->post_status
        && ! in_array( $post_before->post_status, [ 'editing', 'publish' ]  )
        && 'post' === $post_after->post_type
    )
        $wpdb->update( 
            $wpdb->posts, 
            [ 'post_date_gmt' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ], 
            [ 'ID' => $post_ID ] 
        );      

}, 10, 3 );
```

Hopefully you can test this further and adjust to your needs.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the in-depth answer! People like you make the world a better place :)